# How to properly escape a string via PHP and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, escaping

Can someone explain what is the difference between using mysql_real_escape_string on a string or wrapping `` around the column.

For example ``` "insert into table (``column``) values ('$string')" ```

or

```
$escapestring = mysql_real_escape_string($string);
 "insert into table (column) values ('$escapedstring')"
```

What is the difference between these two and what should I use? Thanks.

Comment: You should probably use neither nor. Use bind parameters. That's the safest way. http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/bind-parameters?langtype=php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between the backtick ` and the single quote `'`.

The backtick is intended to escape table and field names that may conflict with MySQL reserved words. If I had a field named `date` and a query like `SELECT date FROM mytable` I'd need to escape the use of `date` so that when MySQL parses the query, it will interpret my use of `date` as a *field* rather than the *datatype* `date`.

The single quote `'` is intended for literal values, as in `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE somefield='somevalue'`. If `somevalue` itself contains single quotes, then they need to be escaped to prevent premature closing of the quote literal.

Answer (score -1):

Those two aren't related at all (as far I know anyway)

From the manual : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

> Escapes special characters in the
>   unescaped_string, taking into account
>   the current character set of the
>   connection so that it is safe to place
>   it in a mysql_query().

So essentially what it does is, it will escape characters that are unsafe to go into mysql queries (that might break or malform the query)

So `o'reily` will become `o\'reily`