# how to escape a string in php?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to properly escape a string via PHP and mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840230/how-to-properly-escape-a-string-via-php-and-mysql)

I'm trying to populate a `MySQL` database, and to do so I'm parsing a data file and running a `INSERT INTO ...` query.
the table `parsonspredictions_R` is structured as:

```
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| drug_a      | blob    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| drug_b      | blob    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| correlation | float   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| p_value     | float   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

However, there are some `drug_x` values which have `'` along, so how could I escape my string in other to ignore or remove those `'` from the string?

Example:

```
INSERT INTO parsonspredictions_R (
    drug_a,
    drug_b,
    correlation,
    p_value
) VALUES(
   '2'-Hydroxyflavanone_28_0',
   'Emodin',
   0.165714,
   0.0019
);
```

Results in:

> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '', 'Emodin', 0.165714, 0.0019 )' at line 1-b

Comment: What database library are you using?

Comment: @Cups not what *database*, but what *library* to access that database. There are 3 in core PHP alone: the old mysql, the newer mysqli, and PDO.

Comment: See [string literals in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html) which talks about escaping. (The `'form'` should be preferred as `"form"` is in violation of ANSI.) However, if being called from, say, PHP (and not just a final query as shown), use proper techniques (ie. placecholders) to prevent [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @Pekka ah - my error sorry chap....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape '-character by typing

```
INSERT INTO parsonspredictions_R (
    drug_a,
    drug_b,
    correlation,
    p_value
) VALUES(
    '2''-Hydroxyflavanone_28_0',
    'Emodin',
    0.165714,
    0.0019
);
```

Or you can put your string in MySQL query in ""-quotes.

edited:
To make your file ready for regex you can use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on text before using regex. It will escape all suspicious characters, like '-character.

Comment: +1 because this is correct and does not deserve a downvote. However, since the question is tagged as PHP it might be advisable to consider how "dynamic data" is inserted.

Comment: @Ianka: the data comes from a file ... which is being parsed using a regex, so I can't escape it manually.

Comment: @philippe  than you can edit your regex (or make another one) to add '' (2 quote symbols) instead of ' (one quote symbol) in text variables

Comment: Take this value:
`Spiro[cyclohexane-1,2'-[2H]cyclopentapyrimidin]-4'(3'H)-one, 1',5',6',7'-tetrahydro- (9CI)_48_3`: I'm using the following regex:

Comment: `$regex = '/(\w*)\s*-\s*([\d\.]+)\s*\(p\s*=\s*([\d\.]+)\)/';`

Comment: you put result from your regex work in some array, yes? then just walk throug this array and change all single qoute symbol on 2 single quote symbols, there will be 2 nested loops and all your string will be escaped. You even don't need a regex for this, you can use simple `str_replace` php function.

Comment: @lanka Don't make me take away my +1! `str_replace` is **not suitable** for preparing SQL data. Search on SO for "PHP sql injection attack".

Comment: @pst but these strings are come from file, there is no user input from posting forms, so there can not be any injection attack. But I'll edit the post and say that str_replace is suitable only for limited situations like this one and not suitable for most other situations.

Comment: @lanka **It does not matter**. Please don't spread the use of a one-off approach that will "sometimes work" (it won't work when the input contains a '\', for instance) when the *accepted approaches* (either using `mysql_real_escape_string` or, better, *placeholders*) will **always work** and do not have issues with invalid data: from a crafty attacker or just unexpected file input. (Changed from +1 to -1.)

Comment: @rst ok im not spreading

Answer (score 1):

Try using this function [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) if you are using mysqli, and if you are not using mysqli a simple google search for: `escapes special characters in a string PHP` would point you to a solution.

If you want to avoid this problem completely you should try using the [PDO class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) and their take on prepared statements.

**Assuming you are using mysqli**

```
$drug_a = mysqli_real_escape_string($drug_a);
$drug_b = mysqli_real_escape_string($drug_b);


INSERT INTO parsonspredictions_R (
    drug_a,
    drug_b,
    correlation,
    p_value
) VALUES(
   $drug_a,
   $drug_b,
   0.165714,
   0.0019
);
```

Comment: @philippe then *specify what database library you are using*

Comment: @philippe - `mysqli` is a PHP *updated* version of the `mysql` native library. It *is* MySQL.