# can't store entry as string for when there's unicode character in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, unicode, doctrine-orm

I have the following string:

```
\ud83d\udc57 DESTINATION OF SHOPAHOLIC\n\u260e 088216013304 \/ 085713900029\n\ud83d\udcf1 BB 328713BD\n\u2712 LINE : ladydhie\n\ud83d\udcb3 BCA \n\ud83d\udc8b KEEP CALM AND HAPPY SHOPPING!!!\ud83d\udc8b
```

that I wanted to store as a string in MySQL however doing a simple insert of this gives me empty. Is there something special that I need to do?

I am using Symfony2 and Doctrine as the ORM. So I have an object called User, which has a column called bio and is stored as a string, however when I do something like:

```
user->setBio(\ud83d\udc57 DESTINATION OF SHOPAHOLIC\n\u260e 088216013304 \/ 085713900029\n\ud83d\udcf1 BB 328713BD\n\u2712 LINE : ladydhie\n\ud83d\udcb3 BCA \n\ud83d\udc8b KEEP CALM AND HAPPY SHOPPING!!!\ud83d\udc8b)
```

this gives me empty bio stored in the DB. What should I do to be able to correctly store this.

Comment: you can escape the string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840230/how-to-properly-escape-a-string-via-php-and-mysql

Comment: @Bob tried that and it still didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that your table columns' collation is `utf8mb4` and the MySQL connection collation is `utf8mb4`.

MySQL's basic `utf8` character set only support characters from the Basic Multingual Plane (3 bytes in UTF-8).  Emoji like U+1F457 DRESS aren't in the BMP so can only be stored in full 4-byte form.

> how do I check the mysql connection collation?

I'm not familiar with Doctrine but it looks like you should be able to set the `charset` on a `pdo_mysql` connection to `utf8mb4`. You could also set the `my.cnf` config `default-character-set` to `utf8mb4`.

Also, I'm not sure what the syntax is you're using above, but PHP doesn't have `\u` escapes. To include a character U+1F457 in a PHP string you should either type it directly as `''`, and save your .php file as UTF-8, or include the UTF-8 byte encoding `'\xF0\x9F\x91\x97'`.

Comment: how do I check the mysql connection collation?

Answer (score -1):

I managed to bypass the whole thing by storing the sting in json_format and perfoming json_decode when i access it :)